# Handling HTTP calls and Function calls while loader is still showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am using angularJS and am trying to display Loader (to ensure that the user doesn't click on anything until an HTTP call is returned with results).

The problem is that I have a function that is being called in between, which causes the loader to vanish, thereby enabling user to click on something while a function is still executing behind.

```
 if (response.data[0].projectionType == "LTLRate") {
                    scf.ConfirmTenderLTLRates(scf.confirmTenderLTLTenderId, scf.SelectedOrderDetails.TLOrderId);
                }

scf.ConfirmTenderLTLRates = function (TenderId, TLOrderId) {
        $("#imgLoading").show(); //Am TRYING to keep the loader running, but fails
        if (TenderId > 0) {
            var requestData = {
                Id: TenderId,
                shipmentId: TLOrderId,
                PROWithTenderConfirm: scf.PROWithTenderConfirm
            };
            ShipmentService.confirmTender(requestData).then(function (response) {
                $("#imgLoading").show();
                if (response.data.Id != null)
                    if (response.data.Id > 0) {
                        scf.SelectedOrderDetails.FreightCharges = parseFloat(response.data.markupTotal).toFixed(2);
                    }
                $('#ShipmentTenderingGrid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();
                SweetAlert.swal("Tender Confirmed Successfully!", "", "success");
                scf.editShipment(TLOrderId, 1);
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be mixing AngularJS code with jQuery code for that. Instead of doing $("#imgLoading").show() you should use ng-show="model.isLoading" in the element with ID imgLoading. This means you should hide or show something base on the state of the model.

Considering that you want to show the loading image based on different functions that run async, you should do ng-show with both variables. Something like this:

```
ng-show="model.isLoading || model.isLoadingOtherStuff"
```

That way, until both are set to false, the loading will be displayed.

Comment: Small addition: when you want to use jQuery in your controller / component / directive use angular.element instead of $()

Comment: I tried adding ng-show and assign values inside controller, however that did not work at all. i am sure something is wrong, but how do we find it ?

Comment: How did you set those variables? and how did you set the ng-show?

Comment: @FranciscoGoldenstein thanks for the reply, I did use ng-show="scf.ShowLoader" and then set the values as scf.ShowLoader=true; wherever i need to replace it with jquery code ..am able to see this working but when it comes to maintaining loader constantly on screen, its failing, it goes off, when it jumps to function ConfirmTenderLTLRates

Comment: But you need to variables to check if you want to show the loader, one for each function as I described in my answer. If you are sharing the same variable among both functions, when one function finishes will set it to false and the loader will be invisible.

Comment: Tried, but i know there is something wrong with this whole code. we gotta finish it fast and have no other way but to use angular-UI-block . between thanks a lot @FranciscoGoldenstein